# SSRS - Merge Repeating Texboxes w/ Distinct Row Values

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Everything except for the name may or may not be different, but it doesn't matter.
[image]

How do you make it so the name and address (first column) can only show once if the value on multiple rows is the same? There is no way to merge the rows together due to the numbers of rows being generated from a group expression. But if there is another way to merge then can someone tell me how to do it? If not, then is there at least a way to blank out the second and third repeating names (and address)?

Comment: Why don't you create a row group using the name field? It will leave only occurrence of each value.

Comment: Well I tried that and it gives me a blank row for every name and then the details are placed in separate rows

Comment: How are you creating the row group? could you edit your question to include a screenshot of your tablix?. Also check [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72649/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you hide repeating values in a tablix column.

In design mode, click on the detail cell that you want to keep from repeating if the values are the same. In this case, you are referring to that one as the *name and address* column.

Look for the `HideDuplicates` property in the Properties pane. Set the value to the name of the dataset the tablix is using.

Now, when you run the report, that value should only show once. The other rows where the value had been repeating will be blank in that cell.

Set the borders appropriately (none, or solid) to make it look like the cells are merged. Doing the above alone will not merge the cells. Only a row group will do that.